# Where can I get a full database of american neighborhoods?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm currently working on a project where I require an extensive hyperlocalised database of US neighborhoods.

I purchased the full US db from http://www.zipcodedownload.com/ but because I am from Australia I didn't realize that each neighborhood in America does not specifically have a zip code (eg meatpacking district new york) so it is not that useful to me.

The db needs to be in a format that can be imported into Mysql and can't be an api. Also needs to have log and lat values for each area.

Thanks

Comment: How are you defining a neighborhood? I would think that would vary greatly from city to city and where would people who don't live in a town fall in the neighborhood definition? I would think that would also vary greatly depending on the database source you used. Neighborhoods are not part of any American address so there is no standrd way to define them.

Answer (score 0):

What about http://aws.amazon.com/datasets/2341 (US Economic Data for 2003-2006 from the The US Census Bureau)

Answer (score 0):

Does the zip code database that you bought include data down to the "zip+4" level? A zip+4 normally identifies one side of a section of a street. That's probably smaller than what you consider a "neighborhood", but you could then aggregate.

Of course I have no idea what data you want ABOUT a neighborhood.